# How to use linq result input sql where in

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have a linq script

```
  var ID = (from item in ConflictDatas.AsEnumerable()
  group item by new
    {
   ID = item.Field<string>("ID"),
   DesignArticle = item.Field<string>("DesignArticle"),
   DesignNo = item.Field<string>("DesignNo"),
   PatternCode = item.Field<string>("PatternCode")
   } into g
     where g.Count() >= 2
     select new
      {
         g.Key.ID
         }).ToList();
```

I want to put this result into a sql commnad.

I try:

```
string sqlwhere;
sqlwhere = string.Join(",", ID);
tsql = @"
Insert  ConflictDesignArticle
Select * from ReadyworkData where ID in (" + sqlwhere + @") ";
```

After compile:

```
Insert  ConflictDesignArticle
Select * from ReadyworkData where ID in ({ ID = SPSOS17040113 },{ ID = 
SPSOS17040115 },{ ID = SPSOS17040114 })
```

How to modify my code. Thanks.

Comment: add `.Select(x=>x.ID)` before `.ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for  Lei Yang help

```
var ID = (from item in ConflictDatas.AsEnumerable()
group item by new
{
 ID = item.Field<string>("ID"),
 DesignArticle = item.Field<string>("DesignArticle"),
 DesignNo = item.Field<string>("DesignNo"),
 PatternCode = item.Field<string>("PatternCode")
 } into g
 where g.Count() >= 2
 select new
  {
     g.Key.ID
     }).Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```